# Fix MBR for a 16-bit intel 80386sx cpu

Tags: mbr, ms-dos, cpu-architecture, 16-bit, fixmbr

i have an old classic computer running ms-dos 3.30 on computer architecture running a 16-bit cpu (80386sx, not to mistake with 80386DX which is 32-bit), i was playing around and messed up the MBR.
I can reinstall the applications so dont really care about the partitions and other information.
Re-installing using the commonly available applications didnt help as all those applications work with either 32bit or 64bit arch.
Used fdisk as well with no joy.
i maybe wrong here about the 32-bit and 16-bit difference causing system not to boot anymore but thats my understanding. Any thoughts on this and tools are appreciated

Comment: With such an old computer, you should also consider the possibility of a disk hardware failure.

Comment: you are right but not a disk failure, works like a charm on other computers, also have a replacement as well.
the disk is a 41MB 3600RPM, the other one is an 105MB similar specs